# How do I concat imported js libraries using Gulp 4?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a main `script.js` that imports both modules I've written in addition to libraries like jQuery and D3. I'm trying to learn Gulp 4 and can get Gulp to concat the files I've written. But my libraries like jQuery and D3 aren't being added into my final scripts file. I can't figure out how to get those libraries rolled into my final script file.

My imports in my scripts.js file where the leagueTeams item seems to flow in fine...

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import leagueTeams from './league-teams';
```

The `js` part of my `gulpfile.js`...

```
// JS FUNCTION
function js() {
  return gulp
    .src(tree.js.src)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/env'],
    }))
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(tree.js.dist));
}
```

When browserSync fires up I get the error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

When I inspect my `scripts.min.js` it shows all my code, but no jQuery or D3 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I was missing some key components like Babelify and Browserify. The following seems to be working as expected.

```
// JS FUNCTION
function js() {
  const b = browserify({
    entries: 'src/js/scripts.js',
    debug: true,
  });

  return b
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', log.error)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(tree.js.dist));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use gulp-rollup (https://github.com/mcasimir/gulp-rollup). This basically let's me import other local js files and rollup will actively import the contents into one contained file. Or multiple files.

here is the node js package https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rollup

```
import rollup from 'gulp-rollup';

function scripts() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/src/js/*.js')
  .pipe(rollup({
      allowRealFiles: true, 
      input: [
          './assets/src/js/default-page.js', 
          './assets/src/js/nms-scholarship-page.js',
          './assets/src/js/scholarship-page.js'
      ],
      output: {
          format: 'umd',
      }
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
  .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/env'],
   }))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(minify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.static))
}
```

This currently takes my 3 inputs and writes to 3 outputs. But, you could run a concat function to concatenate all of these if you want one single bundle.

The code in this github issue helped me understand the code. https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2006